# Difference between using an if statement vs a #if statment

Tags: c, syntax, if-statement

I was wondering if using an `if` statement vs a `#if` and `#ifdef` statement was a matter of style or are there differences in functionality and why you would use one over the others.

Is this the correct way yo use a `#ifdef` statement?

```
#define variable 1

#ifdef variable      //if variable is defined as 1?
//code
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

`#if` is used by the preprocessor and is used to conditionally include sections of code for compilation. A typical use is when a source file must be compiled for different operating systems (or different compilers):

```
#ifdef _WIN32
/* Something specific to windows. */
#else
/* Something not available on windows. */
#endif
```

An `if` statement is used to control the flow of a program during runtime.

Comment: So you can't define it earlier in the code like what I did? It has to be predetermined and specific to configurations of a development kit for example.

Comment: Nope, you can define your own if you wish as you have.

Answer (score 1):

All directives prefixed by `#` are handled by a part of the compiler that runs *before* the compilation, called the [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). That is, for the code in your example if `variable` is not defined the code between the `#ifdef` and the `#endif` will not even be seen by the compiler.

Comment: so i need to define variables before the main code runs? for example i use the "#define variables....." (where i define my global variables) then run the code in my main() function?

Comment: @user1697752 No, they aren't really variables. If you `#define` a "variable" and use it in your normal code, the preprocessor will replace that instance of the name with the value you define it with. So in your example everywhere `variable` is used it will be replaced by the literal number `1` for the compiler to use. This is why it can't be used as a variable, you can't for example assign to a literal number.

Answer (score 1):

The two statement are executed by two different stages of the compiler:

```
#ifdef ...
```

is executed by the preprocessor. It removes or leaves intact its guarded portion of code. This is done at compile time, therefore the condition must be a compile-time constant. If a part of the code is excluded by `#ifdef`, the corresponding code does not go into the compiled executable.

```
if (...)
```

is processed by the compiler, and gets converted into executable code. Its expression can be computed at run-time. Both sides of the expression remain in the compiled executable<sup>*</sup>.

---

<sup>*</sup> Unless an optimizer detects that one part can be removed; this is not common.

Comment: There are occasions where an `if` and an `#if` are nearly the same, but it depends on compiler cleverness. An `if (false)` or equivalent usually skips the block, but syntax errors within the block will still cause a compilation failure. Using `#if` they won't.

Answer (score 1):

There is an important reason for this distinction:

Code 1 -

```
#if SOMETHING
    do_some_c_stuff();
#endif
```

1. If "SOMETHING" is true, we'll call the do_stuff function
2. If "SOMETHING" is false, this code won't be compiled.
3. If "SOMETHING" is not defined in your code base, not be compiled.

Code 2 -

```
#ifdef SOMETHING
    do_some_c_stuff();
#endif
```

1. If "SOMETHING" is defined (true or false) we'll call the do_some function
2. If "SOMETHING" is not defined in your code base, this code won't be compiled

That's why you'll frequently see:

```
#ifdef SOMETHING
#if SOMETHING
    do_some_c_stuff();
#endif
#endif
```

or some combination thereof

Comment: If `SOMETHING` is not defined, it will be defaulted to 0 (false) in an `#if SOMETHING`.

Answer (score 0):

`#ifdef` is preprocessed by the compiler, this mean that the expression is not evaluated at runtime. It's usually used to check for a compile flag.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk(v=vs.100).aspx

Cliffs: It's evaluating the `#if` at compile time, and based on the result, it does the code in the block of code inside of the `#if`...`#endif`.  Common use:

```
#if DEBUG
    // Do some additional logging here we don't want to to in release.
#endif
```

As was already said, you don't have access to local variables, the preprocessor directives access things you've defined.  By default in Visual Studio, `DEBUG` is defined when you have your mode set to `Debug`.  If you add that #if DEBUG` code from above to a project, you'll notice the code inside of it will "grey" out a bit when you switch to Release mode (assuming all default settings).  This is Visual Studio saying that the greyed out code won't be run in the current configuration when you compile.

Answer (score 0):

all line which us the `#` are treated by the compiler (gcc). and not treated in the binary (runtime)

> Is this the correct way yo use a #ifdef statement?
>   --> yes

Answer (score 0):

`#if` and `#ifdef` are evaluated at compile time, they are pre-processor instructions. The item you have named "variable" in your code is not a variable, but a numeric constant that will replace all occurrences of "variable" in the code with 1, before the code is even compiled. All such pre-processor instructions are just indications to the compiler for how it should translate your code into a binary.

An ordinary if-statement is something entirely different, it is part of the actual program itself and performs runtime checks and thereby controls the "flow" of the program.